# how do I implement various methods inside a class construction

Tags: javascript, class

```
class Time{
    constructor(hours,minutes){
        this.hours=hours;
        this.minutes=minutes;
    }

    addTime(val=0,func=showTime){             //How can I write this part too?<--
        this.minutes+=val;
        if(this.minutes>60){
            this.hour++;
            this.minutes-=60;
        }
        return this.func()                   //this was something I was toying with<--
    }

    round(){
        switch(this.minutes%5){
            case 0:break;
            case 1:this.minutes-=1;break;
            case 2:this.minutes-=2;break;
            case 3:this.minutes+=2;break;
            case 4:this.minutes+=1;break;
            default:break;
        }
        //console.log(this.minutes)
        return this.hours+":"+this.minutes;  //here too... I didn't know how to return a method<--     
    }

    showTime(){
        return this.hours+":"+this.minutes;
    }

    
}
```

1. the addTime() function needs to be made in such a way that I can use another method (any one of the two) which I have coded below right after making the alterations.
2. this was my attempt at making a code for a Time class which I was trying to implement in a time tracking js webapp
3. I'm still just starting so any suggestions to improve it must be something a beginner can understand, I sorry for the inconvenience...?:(
4. This is my first post here... I'm not quite sure if I can post this kind of doubts in here so any feedback is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @abhiCoder. Please take note that this community is open for a lot of questions if you have problems with a specific code problem that you are not able to solve with other resources but your Problem seems like a basic programming question. Please try to inform yourself on publicly available resources like https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to access the function of the same class in another function, I'll suggest using the `self` parameter. ex. `def function_name(self, other_parameters)`. Here 'self' denotes the class, then you can call other functions using `self.function_name`.

So, In your program you can call other functions inside of another one by using code like:

```
def func1(self):
     #code
def func2(self):
     self.func1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `return this.func()` to `return func()`.